# Symbolic link bypasses htaccess in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, symbolic-link

I have a protected folder in my server.

```
/var/www/private/
/var/www/private/.htaccess
```

It also has a lot of subfolders with different services.

```
/var/www/private/service1/
/var/www/private/service2/
/var/www/private/service3/
```

Now, i'd like to shorten the url of some services. I'd like to use symbolic links.

```
/var/www/service1 -> private/service1
```

Now the tests:

http://localhost/private/service1 <-- Asks for password, like i want.

http://localhost/service1 <-- **Doesn't ask for password!!**

Is this a general limitation of symbolic links or a misconfiguration issue?
Tried on Fedora and Ubuntu with quite standard configs (i can post them at request).

Answer (score 1):

you probably enabled htaccess only for the target directory. you should also do the same for the symlink itself with:

```
<directory /var/www/symlink>
allowoverride all 
</directory>
```

apache does not process the directives defined for the target directory after finding the symlink in the path.
anyway, I would use an alias in apache config instead of symlinking. for shortening urls, that is.

Comment: I tried <Directory /var/www/service1>... and no joy.

Comment: i apologize, i didn't pay attention to your directory structure. your htaccess is in private, not in private/service1 so a symlink from outside private to service1 will bypass the .htaccess rules. the only fix i see for this is using an alias instead of symlink

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: use the apache2 config instead of the file .htaccess and protect the original directory, not the symlink (or maybe there is a way to tell "Directory" to dereference the symbolic link)

Long answer: I had a similar problem with phpmyadmin. Following [the Debian guide](https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/install-and-configure-phpmyadmin-on-debian-8) I created a symbolic link in the document root:

```
/var/www/html/phpmyadmin  --> /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Then I put the directive

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/phpmyadmin">
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Restricted Content"
   AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
   Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

whithin the /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

It did not work. Eventually I figured out that the path to be protected was not the symlink, but the actual dir:

```
<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin">
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Restricted Content"
     AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
     Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

This one worked.